# How to create a shortcut in my taskbar in windows 10 to GMX email?

Tags: email, shortcuts

I am trying to have a permanent icon on my taskbar to fast open GMX email server. How do I do that?

Thank You.
C. Baron

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a shortcut in my taskbar in windows 10 to GMX email?

Right Click on the Icon and select Pin to Task Bar. See screen shot.

[image: Pin Icon to Task Bar]

.

Alternately try dragging the icon to the taskbar.

Not all icons can be placed on the Windows 10 Task Bar, but if they can, the methods above work on my Windows 10 machine.